# Install yarn error:

Tags: error, installation, yarn

```
yarn install v1.21.1 warning package-lock.json found.
```

Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files.

```
To clear this warning, remove `package-lock.json`.

- [1/5] Validating package.json...
- [2/5] Resolving packages...
- [3/5] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.11: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.11" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
- [4/5] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @magento/eslint-config@1.5.2" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^1.6.0".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@~7.3.4".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@~7.3.4".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@~7.3.4".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@~7.2.0".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx@~7.2.0".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@~7.3.0".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime@~7.4.4".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/preset-env@~7.3.4".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/runtime@~7.4.2".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node@~2.2.0".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "babel-plugin-graphql-tag@~2.0.0".
warning " > @magento/babel-preset-peregrine@1.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-hot-loader@~4.12.17".
warning " > graphql-cli-validate-magento-pwa-queries@1.2.0" has unmet peer dependency "graphql-cli@^3".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@apollo/react-hooks@~3.1.2".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/runtime@~7.4.2".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "apollo-client@~2.6.4".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "informed@~2.11.17".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@~16.9.0".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@~16.9.0".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-redux@~7.1.1".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-router-dom@~5.1.0".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "redux@~4.0.4".
warning " > @magento/peregrine@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "redux-actions@~2.6.5".
warning " > @magento/pwa-buildpack@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-loader@~8.0.5".
warning " > @magento/pwa-buildpack@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "css-loader@~2.1.1".
warning " > @magento/pwa-buildpack@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "terser-webpack-plugin@~1.2.3".
warning " > @magento/pwa-buildpack@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@~4.38.0".
warning " > @magento/pwa-buildpack@5.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "workbox-webpack-plugin@~4.2.0".
warning " > @magento/upward-js@4.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "express@^4.16.4".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "apollo-cache-inmemory@~1.6.3".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "apollo-cache-persist@~0.1.1".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "apollo-client@2.6.4".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "apollo-link-http@~1.5.11".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "braintree-web-drop-in@~1.16.0".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "react@~16.9.0".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-redux@~7.1.1".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "react-router-dom@~5.1.0".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "redux@~4.0.1".
warning " > @magento/venia-ui@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@~4.41.2".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > @magento/pwa-buildpack > graphql-playground-middleware-express@1.7.12" has unmet peer dependency "express@^4.16.2".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > @magento/venia-concept > react-hot-loader@4.12.18" has unmet peer dependency "@types/react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > @magento/venia-ui > @apollo/react-hooks@3.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "@types/react@^16.8.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > @magento/venia-ui > @apollo/react-hooks@3.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^16.8.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > @magento/venia-ui > react-head@3.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@>=16.3".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > @magento/venia-ui > react-slick@0.25.2" has unmet peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 || ^16.0.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > @magento/venia-ui > @apollo/react-hooks > @apollo/react-common@3.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "@types/react@^16.8.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > @magento/venia-ui > @apollo/react-hooks > @apollo/react-common@3.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "apollo-utilities@^1.3.2".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > graphql-cli-validate-magento-pwa-queries > graphql-cli > apollo-codegen > apollo-codegen-core@0.20.1" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > graphql-cli-validate-magento-pwa-queries > graphql-cli > graphql-cli-prepare > graphql-import@0.4.5" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > graphql-cli-validate-magento-pwa-queries > graphql-cli > graphql-cli-prepare > graphql-static-binding@0.9.3" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0".
warning "workspace-aggregator-4d7f1716-16a5-4d05-83b9-41e41f5ec283 > graphql-cli-validate-magento-pwa-queries > graphql-cli > tmp-graphql-config-extension-openapi > @kbrandwijk/swagger-to-graphql@2.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "graphql@^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0".

- [5/5] Building fresh packages...
- [8/12] ⠂ iltorb
- [-/12] ⠂ waiting...
- [3/12] ⠂ iltorb
- [4/12] ⠄ sharp
error /home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments: 
Directory: /home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/node_modules/sharp
Output:
info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.8.1/libvips-8.8.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
ERR! sharp tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=503
info sharp Attempting to build from source via node-gyp but this may fail due to the above error
info sharp Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/page/install for required dependencies
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@10.16.3 | linux | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/node_modules/sharp/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/aspire1030/.node-gyp/10.16.3/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/aspire1030/.node-gyp/10.16.3',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/aspire1030/.node-gyp/10.16.3/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/node_modules/sharp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/node_modules/sharp/build'
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
../src/common.cc:25:22: fatal error: vips/vips8: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
sharp.target.mk:127: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/node_modules/sharp/build'
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-76-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/aspire1030/pwa-studio/node_modules/sharp
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is not related to Magento